# Export Hazelcast Configuration to file

Tags: java, file, config, hazelcast

Does someone knows a way to export a hazelcast config to a file?

I know for importing it, there are following ways:

1. hazelcast.config system property
2. hazelcast.xml file in the working directory
3. hazelcast.xml on the classpath
4. hazelcast-default.xml that comes with hazelcast.jar

But what can I do, if I want to save the actual config as xml. Perhaps for backup purposes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a configuration exporter but there is getter methods on Hazaelcast configuration class `com.hazelcast.config.Config`. You can use them to extract the configuration for you maps, lists, multimaps, groups, etc. For instance:

```
Map<String, ListConfig> listConfigs = config.getListConfigs();
for(ListConfig listConfig = listConfigs.values()) {
    // export the configuration to an output file
    System.out.println("List: " + listConfig.getName()+" has max size: "+listConfig.getMaxSize());
}
```

Comment: Yeah I saw this, but I want a complete config, so I can use this, if I want to backup the application after some failures etc. Thats why I need the whole hazelcast config.xml

Comment: You can get the whole config, as you have getters for other things map, multimap, etc. If you're creating your config through xml than the simpler option would be just to backup these files.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a build in function for this, because I dont want to write my onw config format file.